# Complete but not totally bounded metric space with a certain property

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Give an example of a complete metric space $(X,d)$ and a nested sequence of nonempty closed BALLS $A_n = \bar{B}(x_n,r) = \{y \in X : d(x_n,y) \leq r\}$ such that $\bigcap_n A_n = \emptyset$.

So we're looking for a complete space that is not totally bounded (since for compact spaces it's easy to show that we can never find such sets). My first thought was to jump $\mathbb{R}$ in the discrete metric, but it doesn't work. There are such sets, just no such balls.

I'm beginning to wonder if there is such a space.

Comment: Is that even possible? In a complete metric space a nested sequence of closed non-empty sets with diameter approaching $0$ intersects in exactly one point, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @StefanH. But here it is not demanded that the diameters shrink to $0$. It _might_ be possible then.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Hmm...  I find it hard to imagine that when the diameters shrink to $0,$ then the intersection is non-empty, but when they have a lower bound, then the intersection is empty. That's counter-intuitive :-)

Comment: Are you sure there is just a space?

Comment: @StefanH. I agree, but I see no immediate proof that it is impossible.

Comment: No, I'm not sure, but I can't prove that there isn't.

Comment: @ Stefan H. Also, your first comment is false. The space needs to be compact to guarantee that. E.g. the sets $(0,1/n)$ are all closed in $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete metric and their diameters $\to 0$ but their intersection is empty.

Comment: I think since the space is complete, such space does not exist.

Comment: @user93370: No, in the discrete metric the intervals $(0,1/n)$ all have diameter $1.$ :-)

Comment: When $diam(A_n)\to 0$, choose $x_n\in A_n$, then $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, it converges to a point $x$. Since $A_n$'s are all closed, $x\in A_n$ for any $n$.

Comment: Right, so we are left with the case where $diam(A_n) \to k$ for some $k > 0$.

Comment: When $diam(A_n) \to k$ for some $k>0$, we can find a nest of closed set $B_n$ such that $diam(B_n) \to 0$ and $B_n\subset A_n$.

Comment: But again, aren't the $(0,1/n)$ intervals in the discrete metric a counterexample?

Comment: @user93370 Those are non-empty nested closed sets with finite diameter and empty intersection, but they are not _balls_. And that's the difficult part.

Comment: @user93370 Sorry, I have made a mistake and how about this modification of your example: $\mathbb{R}$ with discrete topology but with distance $d(x,y)=|x-y|+1$. In this case $(0, 1/n)$ is a closed ball but a little difference is that the "$\leq$" in definition of $A_n$ need to replaced by "$<$".

Comment: @user93370 Another example: $\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ with the metric above. This example resolve the trouble in the above example, so maybe it is better.

Comment: In the above example, let $A_N=\{\frac{1}{n}:n\geq N\}$.

Comment: Yes, I had come up with something like that last night! You should write that in the "answers" section, though :).